# How to sync unsynced commits in GitHub Windows client?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

How do i sync unsynced commits in GitHub for Windows?

---

i made some changes to a file a month ago. i just realized today that they didn't go anywhere; the GitHub web-site has no history of my changes.

The client has no indication that anything is out of date (there are no *"uncommitted changes"*). But there **are** *"unsynced commits"*:

[image]

How do i sync unsynced commits?

## I tried nothing, and i'm fresh out of ideas

i tried clicking the `sync` button (whatever that means), but all i get (after a progress bar moves for about 7 seconds) is:

> failed to sync branch
>   You might need to open a shell and debug the state of this repo.

[image]

Clicking **OPEN SHELL**, causes a powershell prompt to appear, where i type:

```
debug the state of this repo
```

But that doesn't seem to do it:

[image]

How do i sync unsynced commits in the **GitHub for Windows** client?

## Bonus Reading

- [How to sync unsynced commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729462/how-to-sync-unsynced-commits) (when your *"head"* is *"detached"*)

Comment: It's slightly gobsmacking that with 51.8k rep you typed that into a command shell. Anyway, 1) the commits you do go to your local repo. The sync button pushes those commits to the Github repo. Git is a DVCS, and as such means you have a local repo and a remote repo that you can gradually push local repo commits to. 2) This Github client error message is a bit cryptic. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @RobertGrant The error message doesn't explain what i *should* type, so i only try what it suggests. I have run out of patience for a source control system that fails so spectacularly. Also, anything after the first horizontal line in the question is wasted filler material. It is used to bulk out the question, to make it look like i put forth research effort. (Ideally the question have ended after the first line, but people tend to be unhelpful for one-line questions)

Comment: The system is fine; someone's just written a pretty client that currently has limited functionality and sometimes unhelpful error messages. For future reference: typing an English sentence into a command prompt will work rather rarely. Also, one liner questions are fine if appropriate; the trick is to have enough technical expertise to know when that is. Anyway, back to my question: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @RobertGrant No, i am not behind a proxy.

Comment: Do you have write permissions on that repo?

Answer (score 2):

Open the Git Shell and type `git status` this should give some more details as to what is wrong.

Comment: I tried this, and the message I got was `nothing to commit, working directory clean`. It appears that there are still some unsynced commits, though.

Answer (score -2):

Open the git shell and try to manually, push it: 
First type: "git remote add origin "https://" ", it should say that remote origin already exists. Then try: "git push -u origin master"

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.